# DBpedia SPARQL and predicate connection

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I've got a problem with the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint because the properties of the properties like the label of `rdf:type` are not stocked in the endpoint. So when I run this query:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE{
  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place> ?predicat ?object .
  OPTIONAL{?predicat rdfs:label ?label}
}
```

I've got nothing for ?label.

If someone got any idea to solve this problem it would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you really trying to get the labels for the properties of a class? You can find them if you deference the predicate URLs in your example, like [link](http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label), but they aren't very interesting. The label for rdf-schema#label is "label", for example...

Comment: @glennmcdonald: I would disagree with the statement that predicate labels are not interesting, in particular, that they are less interesting than any other labels. After all, one could argue that labels are generally not interesting as the English label of [`http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Town`](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Town) (not a predicate) is simply *town*. On the other hand, the label for [`http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink`](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink), which is used as a predicate, is a quite informative *Link from a Wikipage to an external page*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the real labels from DBpedia because the SPARQL endpoint doesn't have them. But you can take the local name of the property URI. So, for rdfs:subClassOf you'd get "subClassOf". That's better than nothing. This can be done using Virtuoso's (non-standard) `bif:regexp_replace` function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (bif:regexp_replace(STR(?p), "^.*[/#]", "") AS ?label) WHERE {
   <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place> ?p ?o .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a SPARQL solution. Dbpedia doesn't have the data you want, and I couldn't easily find a SPARQL endpoint for that RDF at W3C. And I don't think the Virtuoso dbpedia endpoint supports federation yet, even if we did find a SPARQL endpoint for W3C.

Happy to be proven wrong on any of those points.